# Ubuntu / Windows 7 No-FI fix

Tags: wireless, software-installation

I have an Inspiron 1525 with windows 7 on it. I shrank the partition and installed Ubuntu 16.04.
I now have no way to connect to the internet via WI-FI in the Ubuntu GUI.
I swap to Win7 and have Wi-Fi just fine.
Should I try a wired connection and do the upgrade or driver installs or what??

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea :-)

Comment: you can alo getthe drivers while in windows and save them, then mount the windows partition so linux can read the files. what wifi card do you have?

Comment: please. provide some information about your wifi card.

Comment: I believe, without the machine in front of me, JR356 miniPCI-E...... Additional drivers / propreitary drivers brought to my attention the wireless Braodcom and i swapped to the propreitary driver then restart and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am user Cr33pD3ath got a New user name and email.
I found the Driver issue resolve from this page: ([Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers))
Just a note after:
 [sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer]
 [sudo reboot]

I had to follow up with:
[sudo modprobe -r b43]
[sudo modprobe b43]
[sudo rfkill unblock all ]

Once that was complete No-Fi issue fixed!!
Wifi is on and working great, so far.
Thanks for the help!!!